# Reading an Excel file with C# with misplaced header row

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledbconnection

I have been using `OleDbConnection` to read an Excel files from my C# code.

Everything work great when the file has a top header row and the data following it down.

The following connection string is used:

```
 var query = "SELECT [Col1],[Col2],[Col3] FROM [Sheet1$]";
```

Now I need to process an Excel file that has an obligatory content from the first down to the 15th row. The 15th row is a header row and the rest is the data for the rows.

How can I read such a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from 15th row, modify your query to use table name as FROM `[Sheet1$A15:ZZ]`-

```
var query = string.Format("select [Col1],[Col2],[Col3] from [{0}${1}]", "Sheet1","A15:ZZ");
```

A15 represents header row.

Make sure that you have set `"HDR=YES"` in your connection string.